# Facebook crash with empty email in graph

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

I am a bit new to swift and could use some help. I am successfully running a Facebook SDK graph request, and saving pieces of it to my database on Parse. The issue is that if the user does not allow their email to be read, my app crashes because the object is empty. Here is my code:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me",
                              parameters: ["fields": "id, name,friends, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, gender,taggable_friends"])
                .start(completionHandler: { (connection, result , error) -> Void in

                    let data:[String:AnyObject] = result as! [String : AnyObject]
                    print(data)
                    PFUser.current()!["fb_id"] = data["id"] as? String
                    PFUser.current()!["name"] = data["name"] as? String

                    PFUser.current()!["email"] = data["email"] as! String
                    PFUser.current()!["gender"] = data["gender"] as! String
                    PFUser.current()?.saveInBackground()
```

Can someone help me edit the email line to say if it is empty do not attempt to force save it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is the standard way to safely unwrap an optional in Swift:

```
if let email = data["email"] as? String {
    PFUser.current()!["email"] = email
}
```